# Completely confused about CORS. What is a preflight error?

Tags: javascript, cors

What else do I need to add?  First it was the a no header error, now its a preflight error(whatever that is).  I tried turning it off via a browser plug-in as that was recommended.
Error:

> index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WORLDBANK/' from origin 'null'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight
>   request.

Request:

```
function getMetals() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WORLDBANK/'
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('ok');
        }
        else {
            console.log('not ok');
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xhr.send();
}

getMetals();
```

Comment: Server decide whether it allows CORS, not the client. It's probably server setting.

Comment: @Konowy I've tried 2 different APIs now, and same error, but Pokeapi works fine.  If its a public API shouldn't it allow CORS, isn't that the whole point of it being public?

Comment: Could be that if you're just viewing the file in your browser, i.e. your url in the browser starts with `file:///`, the browser does not send an `Origin` header which fails the server's specified CORS policy (which the error "...from origin 'null' has been blocked..." suggests). If you serve your `index.html` via some web server on your local host, or try running it in JSFiddle or CodePen or something like that, does it work?

Comment: @cubrr I'm not sure, I haven't learned node yet, ill try codepen, but yes, I am running it in my browser.  I just finished really getting a grasp on Vanilla JS, and Node was next to learn, do I need to learn it before doing this project to make it easier?